# Get access for cell in table view

Tags: ios, swift

I set up my UITableView programmatically, it has 8 cell now. Using Swift, how can I get access for the third cell for example?

Comment: use cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: this has nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create indexpath with section and row details for eg if you need
   third cell of first section

   `let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)`
2. You can pass the above indexpath in the below method. The function
   returns a cell for a table view

   `var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UITableViewCell`